# CSS при высоте блока 4px выглядят все по разному

Tags: html, css, style

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему первый элемент прогрессбара выглядит тоньше чем остальные? По стилизация они одинаковы

```css
.skill-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.skill-text__title {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.skill-text__percent {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.skill-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #D9DBE3;
}
.skill-progress span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FF6F14;
}
.skill-progress__design {
  width: 85%;
}
.skill-progress__programming {
  width: 65%;
}
.skill-progress__marketing {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill">
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Web Design</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">85%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__design"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Programming</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">65%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__programming"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Programming</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">65%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__programming"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Непонятно о чём речь, у меня всё выглядит одинаково

Comment: @andreymal я добавил картинку, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Думаю, что от браузера зависит. У меня, наоборот, в Хроме Web Design кажется толще остальных, а в Мозилле все одинаковые

Comment: @humster_spb не ужели нету решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Хм, а вот в моём хроме действительно тоньше

Comment: @andreymal почему же так?

Comment: А вот непонятно. Вместо 4 пикселей высота полоски 3.999572992324829 пикселей, а почему — не знаю

Comment: В более старом хроме высота ровно 4 пикселя как и должно быть, видимо что-то сломали в последних версиях хрома

Comment: @andreymal понятно, теперь "сиди и ломай голову" из-за разработчиков

Comment: Какая у вас ОС, кстати?

Comment: @andreymal я использую Windows 8.1

Comment: @Лукас, масштаб

Comment: @qwabra Все понял это такой баг

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется в виду [этот](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=739176) баг Firefox, то можно попробовать трюк с поворотом: `transform: rotate(0.0001deg);`

```css
.skill-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.skill-text__title {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.skill-text__percent {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.skill-progress {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  transform: rotate(0.0001deg);
  background: #D9DBE3;
}
.skill-progress span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FF6F14;
}
.skill-progress__design {
  width: 85%;
}
.skill-progress__programming {
  width: 65%;
}
.skill-progress__marketing {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill">
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Web Design</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">85%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__design"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Programming</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">65%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__programming"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill__item">
              <div class="skill-text">
                <p class="skill-text__title">Programming</p>
                <span class="skill-text__percent">65%</span>
              </div>
              <div class="skill-progress">
                <span class="skill-progress__programming"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Сижу на последней лисе, всё [норм](https://i.imgur.com/m17Ssgb.png) (пример от автора вопроса)